# Android zoomable & panneble containerview

Tags: android, zooming, drag, android-framelayout, pan

I ported an Android class to Xamarin. 
This class is for zooming in and dragging different imageViews.
The only problem is that i can't create a relativelayout to position the imageviews with android:layout_toLeftOf etc. (The images appear on top of eachother when i don't use a relativelayout)

When i create a relativelayout, put the imageviews in it (with addview) and add the relativelayout  itself with addView, the first image is missing, even in the beginning. I also tried creating the relativelayout and imageviews in xml but this doesn't work either...

```
public class TouchContainer: FrameLayout, View.IOnTouchListener
{

    private static  Bitmap.Config DEFAULT_COLOR_DEPTH = Bitmap.Config.Argb8888;
    private static  String TAG = "TouchContainer";
    private List<ImageView> items;

    public TouchContainer(Context ctx, IAttributeSet attrs): base(ctx,attrs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("init touchcontainer");
        InitializeViews();  // initialize some sample Bitmaps
    }

    protected void InitializeViews()
    {
        ImageView.ScaleType scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.Matrix;

        items = new List<ImageView>();  

        ImageView iv = new ImageView (Context);
        iv.SetImageDrawable (Resources.GetDrawable (Resource.Drawable.parkZoomOut3));
        iv.SetScaleType (scaleType);
        iv.SetOnTouchListener (this);
        items.Add(iv);
        iv.Id=7654;

        ImageView iv2 = new ImageView (Context);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WrapContent, LayoutParams.WrapContent);
        lparams.AddRule(LayoutRules.RightOf, iv.Id);
        //ImageView iv2=GetChildAt(0).FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.ivRight);
        iv2.SetImageDrawable (Resources.GetDrawable (Resource.Drawable.logo_home));
        iv2.SetScaleType (scaleType);
        iv2.SetOnTouchListener (this);
        items.Add(iv2);

        AddView (iv);
        AddView (iv2);

        matrix.PostScale(0.5f, 0.5f, 550, 400);
        transformImages(matrix);
    }

    protected void transformImages(Matrix matrix) 
    {
        foreach (ImageView image in items) 
        {
            image.ImageMatrix=matrix;
        }
    }

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();

    // states
    static int NONE = 0;
    static int DRAG = 1;
    static int ZOOM = 2;
    int mode = NONE;
    static int CLICK = 3;


    PointF start = new PointF();
    PointF mid = new PointF();
    float oldDist = 1f;

    public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("touched");

        switch (e.Action) {
        case MotionEventActions.Down:
            Console.WriteLine ("down");
            savedMatrix.Set(matrix);
            start.Set(e.GetX(), e.GetY());
            mode = DRAG;
            break;
        case MotionEventActions.Pointer2Down:
            Console.WriteLine ("pointer2down");
            oldDist = spacing(e);
            if (oldDist > 10f) 
            {
                savedMatrix.Set(matrix);
                midPoint(mid, e);
                mode = ZOOM;
            }
            break;
        case MotionEventActions.Up:
            Console.WriteLine ("up");
            // figure out if user clicked
            mode = NONE;
            int xDiff = (int) Math.Abs(e.GetX() - start.X);
            int yDiff = (int) Math.Abs(e.GetY() - start.Y);
            if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK)
                PerformClick(); 
            break;
        case MotionEventActions.Pointer2Up:
            Console.WriteLine ("pointer2up");
            mode = NONE;
            break;
        case MotionEventActions.Move:
            Console.WriteLine ("move");
            if (mode == DRAG) {
                Console.WriteLine ("drag");
                matrix.Set(savedMatrix);
                matrix.PostTranslate(e.GetX() - start.X,
                    e.GetY() - start.Y);
            }
            else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                Console.WriteLine ("zoom");
                float newDist = spacing(e);
                if (newDist > 10f) {
                    matrix.Set(savedMatrix);
                    float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                    matrix.PostScale(scale, scale, mid.X, mid.Y);
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        transformImages(matrix);
        return true;
    }

    private float spacing(MotionEvent e) 
    {
        float x = e.GetX(0) - e.GetX(1);
        float y = e.GetY(0) - e.GetY(1);
        return FloatMath.Sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent e) 
    {
        float x = e.GetX(0) + e.GetX(1);
        float y = e.GetY(0) + e.GetY(1);
        point.Set(x / 2, y / 2);
    }
}
```